# Controllers should contain all the requests from a specific entity or screen?

Tags: design-patterns, controller, request, entity

Controllers should contain all the requests from a specific entity or screen? For example, lets say we have a screen where whe can save new clients of a Electronic shop, edit exiting ones, etc. So we could create a ClientController. We have other screen where we can save and update our electronic components stock. So we could create a StockController.
But, what about if we have other screen where we are asked to show a list of clients and a list of the stock components. Where do these two requests should go?

1. Should the last two requests should go to a different controller named ListsController or something similar?
2. Should the list of clients should go to the ClientController and the list of stock to the StockController?

What do you think are the benefits or reasons to choose any of the options?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to model your system around the Domain, instead of the "boundaries". Controllers sit on the boundary, they represent your entry point.

Instead, make sure your Domain Models are not anemic. They should expose well-defined operations. TDD can help a lot with that.

Once you have a good understanding of your Domain, you can think about which operations really "deserve" to be exposed to the outside world. Then you can start adding Controllers.

Normally you should have a 1-1 mapping between Aggregates and Controllers, but that can change based on what kind of system you're developing.

Comment: Ok, but in the example I explained, what would be your choice? Thanks

Comment: from an API perspective, you would have something like:

- GET /api/v1/clients  , returns the archive
- GET /api/v1/clients/123  , returns the client details
- POST /api/v1/clients  , creates a new client
- PUT /api/v1/clients/123  , updates the client details
-DELETE  /api/v1/clients/123  , deletes the client 

once you've got your API, you can attach any kind of UI to it. At that point it would highly depend on your frontend choice.